# How to safely remove Auth from a nodejs web-app

Tags: node.js

I cloned this repo and have it on my local;

https://github.com/vinitkumar/node-twitter

Right now it uses Github auth, which I’m still debugging. I’d like to remove Github auth completely so I can look at it on my local.

Once I make a new git branch, what’s the safest way to remove authentication?

I'm not sure of the proper procedure for removing npm packages, or what pitfalls I should look out for.

The web-app needs to act like users are already authenticated.

Comment: I didn't investigate deeper, but it feels like a simple tweak on the this config file should easely disable auth https://github.com/vinitkumar/node-twitter/blob/develop/config/middlewares/authorization.js

Comment: Commenting out the first function might work, thanks. I was worried I would have to alter 5-6 different files. But just disabling 'isAuthenticated' seems logical and elegant. Cheers.

Comment: It's still redirecting to login... I need to remove redirects from several files.

Comment: after second though, you should be able to mimic auth process, with `isAuthenticated()` returning true should not be to hard somehow mocking user credentials onto the `req.user`